# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' and 'THEN'., While adding the column(s) to an existing table table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

While adding the column(s) to an existing table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM datab2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE table_name = 'f1'
                AND table_schema = 'datab2'
                AND column_name = 'c4') 
THEN
    ALTER TABLE f1 
    ADD c4 nvarchar(50)
END IF;
```

I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' and 'THEN'

Comment: Which db engine? MySQL? MSSQL (T-SQL)? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Syntax you are using is wrong. An `IF` requires a `BEGIN` and`END`, try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM datab2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE table_name = 'f1'
                AND table_schema = 'datab2'
                AND column_name = 'c4') 
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE f1 
    ADD c4 nvarchar(50)
END;
```

Comment: An [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) statement _can_ control a [statement block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql), but a single statement is also allowed..

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
    (
    ...
    )

    BEGIN
        ...
    END
```